# Passing variables to hive query in pyspark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to execute a query against hive table using spark sql.

The below works fine

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]".enableHiveSupport().appName("test").getOrCreate()
df=spark.sql("select * from table_name where date='2021-05-16' and name='xxxx'")
```

But I want to pass date and name as a variable and not hardcode it into SQL.

Is there a way to pass date=current_date instead of hardcoding the value

I am trying to pass current date as date to query using time.strftime and name I have to pass it from another variable
name='xxxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you can to pass the variables from outside of the py file?

if it is , you can try this

```
import sys
day = sys.argv[1]
df=spark.sql("select * from table_name where date='%s'" % day)
```

```
spark-submit --master yarn test.py 2021-09-17
```

Comment: I am trying to pass current date to SQL. Current date is got by time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: @Padfoot123 repalce day as time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")?

Comment: Thank you. What If there are multiple values that I have to pass as variables. Let's say I have to check another column for which I have to pass variable to SQL. Can you help me with that pls

Comment: may you should better translate you requirement to sql. you want to filter by another column?

Comment: Yes.i want to filter by another column and I have to pass it as variable to my SQL. So now there are 2 variables I have to pass to my sql

Comment: sorry , i can't get your point. If you need to pass a variable to replace your 'xxxx', try this `df=spark.sql("select * from table_name where date='%s' and name = '%s'" % (day, name))`

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this out